# Trying to get property 'datep' of non-object?

Tags: laravel

I have two tables POINTAGES and EMPLOYEES Between them is a relation hasMany and belongsTo, I want to display table POINTAGES from
SalarieController gives me error Trying to get property 'datep' of non-object ?.

**consule.blade.php**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>date</th>
                    <th>chantier</th>
                    <th>ouvrage</th>
                    <th>nombre jour</th>
                    <th>solde</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  @foreach($pointages as $pointage)
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{ $pointage->datep }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $pointage->chantier }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $pointage->ouvrage }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $pointage->nbrj }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $pointage->solde }}</td>
                    <td></td>

                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
</table>
```

**SalarieController**

```
public function consulter()
     {

      $salaries = Salarie::with('pointages')->get();
      $pointages = DB::table('pointages')->pluck("datep","id")->all();
      return view('salarie.consulter', compact('salaries','pointages'));
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('consulter', 'SalarieController@consulter');
```

Model Salarie

```
public function pointages(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pointage');
    }
```

**Model Pointage**

```
/**
     * 
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'salarie_id', 'datep', 'solde', 'nbrj' , 'ouvrage' , 'chantier' , 'prime' ,
    ];
    public function salarie(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Salarie');
    }
```

**migration salarie_id**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('pointages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('salarie_id')->unsigned()->after('id');
            $table->foreign('salarie_id')->references('id')->on('salaries');  
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is because you've used `->all()`. `all()` on a collection will return an array. Also, you're plucking the `datep` value so `$pointage` will be the `datep` value. You will not be able to access chantier, ouvrage, nbrj or solde though because you've used pluck.

Comment: thx for u answer ,but how can resolve this error

Comment: just get rid of the pluck method and try again

Comment: i dont know how ,can u writ salarieController plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this issue is because you've used `all()` which when used on a collection will return an array (which is why the error says `non-object`).

The next issue you're going to face is that you won't have `chantier`, `ouvrage`, `nbrj` or `solde` in your results because you're using `pluck` which will only return a single value from a row in your database
([Pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#retrieving-results) -- scroll down to the heading **Retrieving A List Of Column Values**).

To get around both of these issues you just need to change `->pluck("datep","id")->all()` to `get()`.

This will mean that your controller method will look something like:

```
public function consulter()
{
  $salaries = Salarie::with('pointages')->get();
  $pointages = DB::table('pointages')->get();

  return view('salarie.consulter', compact('salaries','pointages'));
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use Eloquent you can change the `$pointages` line to be:

```
$pointages = Pointage::all();
```

(Don't forget to import the model in to your controller).

Answer (score 1):

The method `pluck()` will return an array of your id's plucked to the datep values. So you can't access the value by `$pointage->datep`. Also you can't reach the other properties like chantier, ouvrage ... when you use `pluck()`. Just get rid of the pluck method and iterate over the collection given by `all()` and access the values from the model.
You can do `Pointage:all()` when using your model or `DB::table('pointages')->get();` when using QueryBuilder.

Comment: i dont know how ,can u writ salarieController plz

Comment: Select the code `->pluck("datep","id")` in your code editor and press the delete button...

Comment: @NajibMarzouk just delete ->pluck("datep","id") from you SalarieControllr :)

Comment: @TimLewis he give me another error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

Comment: Change `->all()` to `->get()`.

Comment: yes, or just use your model Pointage like this: Pointage::all()

Comment: @Lukas i try $salaries = Salarie::with('pointages')->get();
     // $pointages = DB::table('pointages')->get();
       Pointage::all() ;
      return view('salarie.consulter', compact('salaries','pointages')); but not work

Comment: $pointages = Pointage::all(); should do the job OR $pointages = DB::table('pointages')->get(); with the first assignment you use your model and with the second one the query builder. first one is more common